# How to create 2 different instances from the same class?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, instance

How can I display, in the console, two instances of the class Cat : Skitty, 9 years and Pixel, 6 years ?

```
(() => {
    class Cat {
        constructor(name, age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("run").addEventListener("click",() => {
    // your code here

    })

})();
```

Thanks in advance and sorry if the question in silly, I'm learning !

Comment: `new Cat("Skitty", 9)` and `new Cat("Pixel", 6)`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Answer (score 0):

```js
const instance1 = new Cat('Skitty', 9);
const instance2 = new Cat('Pixel', 6);
console.log(instance1, instance2);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I was thinking way to complicated !

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score 0):

instantiate and log

did I understood well?

```js
class Cat {
    constructor(name, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}

console.log(
  new Cat('Skitty', 9),
  new Cat('Pixel', 6),
)
```